# find the antiderivative for a function

Tags: calculus

---

Hi!
I'm a little confused about a calculus exercise.
Can someone please check if my logic is right?

The task:
Find the antiderivative for a function $f$ if $f$ is a continuous function and if $F'(x)=f(x)$ for all real numbers $x$, of $\int_{1}^{4}{f(2x)\,dx}$.

As far as I understand the answer is going to be $2F(4)-2F(1)$?
Any help appreciated

Comment: There is no "the" antiderivative of a function $f$. If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then so is $F+C$ for any constant $C$. // Did you copy the problem incorrectly? Do you mean $f(2x)$ in the integrand?

Comment: It asked if $\int_{1}^4(2x) dx$ is equal to 2F(4) − 2F(1). I know that antiderivative of f(2x) is (2x^2)/2, but I'm confused about this exercise

Comment: There is no $f$ in $\int_1^4(2x)dx$. I think you mean $\int_1^4f(2x)dx$.

Comment: Yes, exactly this

Comment: Then could you please edit your question?

Comment: Already edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

There is no "the" antiderivative of a function $f$. If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then so is $F+C$ for any constant $C$.

The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$, then
$$
\int_p^q f(x)dx=F(q)-F(p)
$$

But now you have $
\int_a^b f(2x)dx$. By a change of variable
$$
\int_a^b f(2x)dx=\frac12\int_{2a}^{2b}f(u)du\tag{1}
$$
You can now apply the fundamental theorem of calculus to the right-hand side of (1).

For your problem, $a=1$, $b=4$.